# Is the rank of a free group unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Dummit&Foote - Abstract Algebra p.217

> A group $F$ is free group if there is some set $S$ such that $F=F(S)$. The cardinality of $S$ is called the rank of $F$.

Since it is unique, he may have said "the rank".

How do I prove this?

Comment: If you are just interested in the case where $S$ is finite, you may notice that $|\mathrm{Hom}(F(S), \mathbb{Z}_2)|= 2^{|S|}$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Consider the normal subgroup $H$ of $F(S)$ generated by all the elements $x^2$, $x \in F(S)$. 
Then $F(S)/H \simeq\mathbb({Z}/2)^{(S)}$, a vector space over the field $\mathbb{Z}/2$ with bases
the elements of $S$.